# What does [ὀλίγου] ἐμαυτοῦ ἐπελαθόμην actually MEAN?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, nuance

The first sentence of the Apology of Socrates is:

> Ὅτι μὲν ὑμεῖς, ὦ ἄνδρες Άθηναῖοι, πεπόνθατε ὑπὸ τῶν ἐμῶν κατηγόρων, οὐκ οἶδα· ἐγὼ δ' οὖν καὶ αὐτὸς ὑπ' αὐτῶν ὀλίγου ἐμαυτοῦ ἐπελαθόμην, οὕτω πιθανῶς ἔλεγον.

I've seen several different translations for the phrase *ὀλίγου ἐμαυτοῦ ἐπελαθόμην*:

- I almost forgot myself.
- I was almost carried away with myself.
- I almost didn't recognize myself.
- I almost forgot who I was.

What is he actually saying?

In context—"How *you* felt about the prosecution I don't know; as for *me*, they were so convincing that I almost ______, and yet almost nothing they said was true"—the most rhetorically *logical* thing for it to mean is something like "I almost forgot that I am who I am instead of who they said I am." But my view of what's logical and what Plato actually wrote don't necessarily have anything to do with each other.

In case it's helpful to know when answering, I know very little Greek—certainly not enough to read this sentence if I hadn't read it already years ago when I knew more than I do today. I know that *ἐμαυτοῦ* means "of myself" and *λανθάνομαι* is middle and means "I escape the notice of," though I'm not sure what flavor the prefix *ἐπι* adds. [**EDIT:** I see from Alex B's comment that λανθάνω, the active, rather than the middle that Socrates uses, is actually "I escape the notice of."] In the dictionaries I looked in, there was no entry for the verb as a reflexive.

Thoughts?

Comment: Might one read this as "I almost forgot about my own position"?

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense—like, I almost forgot I was sitting in a courtroom on trial for my life.

Comment: This question was flagged as off-topic. I remind everyone that our [tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour), [topic help page](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [meta discussions](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) indicate that Greek is on-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ἐμαυτοῦ* is straightforward: it's a genitive singular reflexive pronoun, "of myself".

*Ἐπελαθόμην* is more interesting. This is the first-person singular aorist active indicative of *ἐπι-λανθάνομαι*. *Λανθάνομαι* means "to forget", but I've never seen this verb with the prefix *ἐπι* before, and LSJ doesn't even have an entry for it. However, there *is* an adjective *ἐπίληθος*, "causing to forget" with a genitive object (compare *Λήθη*). So the prefix doesn't seem to change the meaning significantly, and seems to just be intensive.

So I would translate this literally as "I really forgot myself", or more idiomatically "I really forgot who I was".

(PS: while the active *λανθάνω* does mean "to escape the notice of", the middle *λανθάνομαι* has the different meaning of "forget" in Classical times.)

Comment: Thanks so much. Where do you get the "really" from?

Comment: @JoelDerfner When a prefix doesn't seem to change the meaning of a word at all, I tend to treat it as intensive.

Comment: LSJ does have an entry, but it's under ἐπιλήθω. For the middle they give the translation "let a thing escape one, forget, lose thought of", citing this Plato passage for this sense. (It doesn't seem to have an intensive sense -- it's just the normal way of saying "forget".)

Answer (score 6):

Montanari ([an iPad app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gi-vocabolario-della-lingua-greca/id1163762401), in Italian) - you will need sense 2 medio (**2 middle: forget, forget about**); also available [online](http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/search#dictionary=montanari&id=44351) in English (subscription only). It's called [the middle voice](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007%3Apart%3D4%3Achapter%3D44%3Asection%3D104).

[image]

Comment: Montanari has an English translation now published by Brill (just a couple years ago).

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I know! I have both the hardcover and the online version.